# Is there any way to divide two DateComponents operands in swift

Tags: swift

I can get the difference between two particular dates which will be equal to total number of dates. Now I want to divide working days with total number of days and get output as an integer.

```
 @IBAction func go(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let task = Habits(context: context)


    //total number of days started here
    //last date
    let ldate = "2019-02-15"
    let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateFormat = "yy-MM-dd"
    let formatedStartDate = dateformatter.date(from: ldate)
    //last date
    //current date
    let cDate = Date()
    task.sDate = cDate
    //current date
    let components = Set<Calendar.Component>([.day])
    let differenceOfDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: formatedStartDate!, to: cDate)
    print("difference starts from here!!")
    print(differenceOfDate)
    //total number of days ended here


    //working days
    let wDate = "2019-02-15"
    let wDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    wDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yy-MM-dd"
    let wformatedStartDate = wDateFormatter.date(from: wDate)
    let wcDate = Date()
    task.sDate = wcDate
    let wcomponents = Set<Calendar.Component>([.day])
    let wdifferenceOfDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents(wcomponents, from: wformatedStartDate!, to: wcDate)
    print("difference starts from here!!")
    print(wdifferenceOfDate)
    let per = differenceOfDate/wdifferenceOfDate //error:Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'DateComponents' 
    //working days ended here
}
```

Comment: I mean like if total number of days are 5 and I count number of days to be 3 days then I want to divide the 3 by 5 get the percentage of working days. Basically I want to get the percentage of working days

Comment: You’re getting `DateComponents` and trying to divide them. You can do something like `let dayDifference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate, to: now).day!` to get the number of days (note the `.day` at the end). And because these are integers, you want to convert to floats or doubles before you divide, e.g. `let per = Float(dayDifference) / Float(wDayDifference)`.

Comment: I’m not sure about your “working days” mechanism, tho. (Frankly, it seems identical to your “calendar days” routine.) What is the intent here? To get the number of weekday days between two dates (i.e. excluding weekends)? Or is there some other intent here?

Comment: im actually trying to make habit tracking app in which I want to show how frequently you do some work.. but now I think I'm gonna use a counter when a habit starts and increase it with date and then I'll take input user and then divide it with counter then I'll get the percentage of how much work that person is doing.... My words may be confusing because I'm unable to state correctly what I want

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly you want a day component from `differenceOfDate` object.

You can get it with `differenceOfDate.day` which is `Optional` value so you need use `if let` for conditional unwrapping. Check below code:

```
let workingDays = 5 //Suppose workingDays is 5.
if let differenceInDay = differenceOfDate.day {
    let divideWithWorkingDay = differenceInDay / workingDays
    print(divideWithWorkingDay) // 1
}
```

Comment: Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'DateComponents' operands

Comment: and the question also

Comment: you need do same as I have showed you with `differenceOfDate` Object. you need to use `wdifferenceOfDate.day` property for `wdifferenceOfDate`

Comment: Can you please help me with how to increase a counter automatically with time, like if date goes fron 24th feb to 25th feb then the value of counter will increase by 1.

Comment: It’s not clear what you are asking. and if this answer helps please mark it correct